# How to show count on app icon like iOS?

Tags: android

I searched many links for the solution, but i did not get any good solution.
If it is not possible to show the count on icon, How facebook and some other apps are doing??

Please help me out.

Comment: It's not possible in Android. Sorry!

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183388/show-badge-count-on-app-icon-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183388/show-badge-count-on-app-icon-in-android)

Comment: I know how to implement widgets, but how can we show the widget in the applications grid?

Comment: You can put widget only in Home screens.

Comment: Then How facebook is showing???

Comment: @M FB and Google used combine services for displays a badge Icons..

Comment: What is combine services?  Can we use that?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

https://github.com/koduribalaji/ShortcutBadger

it will work only respected devices. it Works with LG, Sony, Samsung, HTC and other custom Launchers.